# Can I found out where SIGABRT comes from programmatically in Android app

Tags: java, android, crash, fatal-error, sigabrt

If written a android application for a coffee machine.
It works fine and for the most part is stable.

But once in a while between 10 / 60 days I get the following message:

> E/libc++abi(  536): terminating with uncaught exception of type std::bad_alloc: std::bad_alloc
>
> F/libc    (  536): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 1094 (Thread-48)

I don't know where this is coming from because when this happens the application is doing just showing a image(background) with a dimmed out screen(idle).

Is it possible to catch this signal and log when and where this signal is generated?

I can also see the memory usage of the app and it seems fine to me.

> Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 91639(5MB) AllocSpace objects, 151(2MB) LOS objects, 37% free, 26MB/42MB, paused 1.426ms total 102.365ms

Hope it's clear

Steven